# Updating rails database with a serialized array from radio buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button

I have a database with a bunch of users; among their attributes are preferences for the days of the week they want to work (Sunday..Saturday, and the preferences range from never/rarely/okay/preferred). This is stored in a serialized hash user.day_pref.

It displays fine, but does not seem to update from the form upon submission. Given the serialized storage, I could not quite get formtastic to handle this.

```
%h3 Day of week preferences
- weekdays = I18n.t 'date.abbr_day_names'
- if @user.day_pref.nil?
  / - @user.day_pref = Hash.new {|hash, key| hash[key] = "1"}
  - @user.day_pref = { "0" => "2", "1" => "2", "2" => "2", "3" => "2", "4" => "2", "5" => "2", "6" => "2" }
- pref_name = ["Almost never", "Avoid", "Okay", "Preferred"]
- pref_color = ["red", "yellow", "green", "violet" ]

= form_for @user, :url => user_path(@user), :method => :put do |f|
  %table.table
    %th
      - for day in (0..6)
        %th= weekdays[day]
    %tr
      %td
        - for row in (0..3)
      %br
        = pref_name[row] + " "
        %span{:style => "color:" + pref_color[row]} ♦
      - for day in (0..6)
        %td
          %div
            - for row in (0..3)
              %br= radio_button_tag "@user.day_pref[" + day.to_s + "]", row.to_s, @user.day_pref[day.to_s] == row.to_s
  %tr
    %input{:type => "submit", :name => "day-pref-button", :value => "Update day of week preferences"}
```

The log seems to show the data being submitted successfully (and attr_accessible is set for day_pref), but only the pre-existing values get written to the database, not the new ones selected by the user:

```
Started PUT "/user/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-02 17:04:35 -0800
Processing by UserController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",    "authenticity_token"=>"/auMOXMVOcO4Yrys2FymMPMxi/g/AI3G67vZPcXCb8M=", "@user.day_pref"=>{"0"=>"1", "1"=>"1", "2"=>"1", "3"=>"1", "4"=>"1", "5"=>"2", "6"=>"2"}, "day-pref-button"=>"Update day of week preferences", "id"=>"1"}
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
(0.4ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "updated_at" = '2012-01-03 01:04:35.213534', "day_pref" = '-   --
''0'': ''1''
''1'': ''2''
''2'': ''1''
''3'': ''3''
''4'': ''1''
''5'': ''2''
''6'': ''2''
' WHERE "users"."id" = 1
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/user/1
Completed 302 Found in 61ms
```

I know I'm making some dumb syntactical mistake here, probably in "radio_button_tag" in the view code, but for the last month I've been unable to figure it out for the life of me. Any pointers appreciated.

> > I'm answering my own question, at least in part. I added a couple of lines to the controller, thinking maybe it was not re-packing my data form the array of radio buttons in a way that could be stored.

```
  # PUT /user/1
  # PUT /user/1.json
  def update

    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    # The following, when added, stores the radio button data properly
    if params["@user.day_pref"]
      @user.day_pref = params["@user.day_pref"]
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated' }
        format.json { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

So this is working now, but I'm not entirely sure why I needed the additional line of code.